# Running OSGI from within jboss invoking jax-ws service

Tags: jboss, osgi, apache-felix

I have created some OSGI bundles that I was running in Felix with no problems.  I have a bundle that invokes a call to a jaxws service.  All the stubs for the osgi bundle were generated using cxf-codegen-plugin.  Everything works fine if I startup felix directly and execute my application.

I have recently moved this to having everything running inside of a jboss application server(JBoss 5.1.0.GA).  I am using the [servlet-bridge](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-http-service.html#ApacheFelixHTTPService-UsingtheServletBridge), and starting up felix when my servlet is registered.  Everything starts up find, and all of my bundles are started without error.  However when I execute my application I get the following error:

```
22:23:40,688 ERROR [[proxy]] Servlet.service() for servlet proxy threw exception
javassist.NotFoundException: com.service.ws.Parameters
at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:436)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.DynamicWrapperGenerator.addProperty(DynamicWrapperGenerator.java:226)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.DynamicWrapperGenerator.generate(DynamicWrapperGenerator.java:122)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.processWebMethod(JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.java:796)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.processWebMethods(JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.java:920)
at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.rebuildEndpointMetaData(JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.java:298)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.getPortInternal(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:269)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.getPort(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:200)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:99)
at com.service.ws.JasperService_Service.getJasperServicePort(JasperService_Service.java:46)
at com.service.ws.JasperReportImpl.initializeServer(JasperReportImpl.java:56)
at com.web.ui.ReportWindow.handleParameters(ReportWindow.java:122)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:528)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.felix.http.proxy.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I'm not sure why the javassist classes are not able to find that class.  It is part of the same bundle the call to getPort is made from, and all of this works fine when running from felix directly.

***UPDATE**
I can get past this initial error if I put the jar(bundle) containing the class that is being looked for in the jboss lib directory, thus putting it on the global classpath.  However once I get past that initial resolution error, I then get another error as follows:

```
22:05:10,823 ERROR [ServiceDelegateImpl] Cannot create proxy for SEI com.service.ws.JasperService from: file:/home/work/appservers/osgi/bundle/com.jasper-server-ws-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
22:05:10,824 ERROR [[proxy]] Servlet.service() for servlet proxy threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface com.service.ws.JasperService is not visible from class loader
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass(Proxy.java:353)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:581)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.createProxy(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:400)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.getPortInternal(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:273)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.getPort(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:200)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:99)
```

So something is screwed up with the classpath.  I'm not sure why, but it appears that the class pathing for my bundles might be incorrect in some way, but i'm not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem, as raised in your first update, is one of [Java reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

The secret here is to update your `MANIFEST.MF` file to expose `com.service.ws.JasperService` to the class loader. Following [this guide](http://billhiggins.us/blog/2011/02/24/using-reflection-in-osgi/), you might try something like:

`Export-Package: com.service.ws.JasperService`

Best of luck with your project.